# Rendered image is way too pixelated

Tags: rendering

[image]

When I render, I get an image that is pixelated far beyond recognition.

Comment: Have you considered researching within Cycles settings such as Sampling Tab/ samples render and samples viewport? (names may differ slightly for different versions Blender)  Please see denoising.   You can search those topics here at BSE and there are tutorials at the website which has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  I do recognize some structure in your image as opposed to random noise.  Keep in mind Blender allows low compute requirements render and high compute requirement render so you can decide when the work is best for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Resolution $X$ and $Y$ settings for the **Render Dimensions** determine the render size in pixels.

But when you use **percentage** control, the number of pixels will be reduced if you use a smaller number than 100%.

In this example, a 1920 x 1080 image is rendered at 1%, yielding an image measuring of only 19 x 10 pixels.

Hardly enough pixels to make the sense of the original scene.

[image]

Comment: thank you! why would these dimension settings have been set to 1% by default i wonder

Comment: Blender does not do that on it's own, that much I can tell you. Check how you move the mouse and where you click...

Comment: Hi @DaveFransz Please consider to accept the answer if your issue has been solved. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour